# Why does my JBoss module throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: jboss, classloader, wildfly, jboss-modules

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I have a WAR which I have deployed to a JBoss Wildfly 8.2 instance. Also in Wildfly, I have created two modules:

1. a third party JMS JCA adapter module,
2. and a model module (model.jar) that contains message classes used to communicate between the JMS broker and the WAR

The WAR has a jboss-deployment-structure.xml that declares a dependency on the JCA module:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.thirdparty.mq.ra" slot="main"/>
            <module name="com.company.model" slot="main">
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The WAR has the model.jar file packaged in its WEB-INF/lib folder.

The JMS module has a dependency on the model module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.thirdparty.mq.ra">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
        <resource-root path="thirdparty-jms-provider.jar"/>
        ...
        <resource-root path="thirdparty-lib.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.company.model"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api"/>  
        <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.invocation"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

When running, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.model.web.dto.WebAuthenticationResponse cannot be cast to com.company.model.web.dto.WebAuthenticationResponse
```

I suspect it is a classloader issue. Is there some extra information I have to specify in the module.xml or jboss-deployment-structure.xml files?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is possibly a conflict between two (or more) versions of com.company.model.web.dto.WebAuthenticationResponse you have in your classpath. Can you check what's in your classpath?

Comment: How can I check the Wildfly classpath? Wildfly loads classes at runtime, so they would not be on the executing command...?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `model.jar` corresponds to your `com.company.model` module, your WAR classloader now sees the model classes twice, both from its own libraries in `WEB-INF/lib` and via the module dependency.

You should either import or embed a module/library, but not both.

By the way, importing a RAR module looks a bit suspicious. You should never depend on the implementation of a resource adapter. Maybe you can factor out an API module and import that.

Comment: Isn't this how people are using ActiveMQ in their Wildfly installations? By creating an activemq module and importing it into their project? Or are they setting activemq as the default JMS provider?